# Datepicker dropwown issue with modal box in firefox only

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, drop-down-menu, datepicker

I am using datepicker in bootbox modal form. I want datepicker with change year and month drop down, which is not coming in firefox but in other browser like chrome and safari and IE datepicker is coming with change month and year dropdown.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking. Could you post some code and elaborate on the specific problem?

Comment: @Robert : I have similar issue the link I have pasted here (http://jsfiddle.net/469zV/). When Date Picker plugin is displayed on a ModelDialog then the Month and Year dropdowns click action does not work. No dropdownlist appreared for month and Year dropdowns for firefox but in chrome and safari and IE Month and Year dropdowns click action is working fine.